# ImportError: cannot import name 'Movie' from partially initialized module 'movie.models' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: django, importerror

I have two apps, **crew** and **movie**, i've put the Movie table as a foreignkey to models on crew like **actor,director** etc so that i can access filmography of each of them.
Also i did the same on Movie table to select each crew member while adding a movie details.

but after entering **python manage.py makemigrations** iam getting the above error.

**crew/models.py**
**This is where the error is showing**

```
from django.db import models
from movie.models import Movie

# Create your models here.
class Crew_Temp(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True,null=True)
    about=models.TextField(max_length=2000,blank=True,null=True)

class Actor(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True,null=True)
    photo=models.ImageField(upload_to='crew/actor')
    slug=models.SlugField(max_length=50,unique=True,blank=True)
    about=models.TextField(max_length=2000,blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
class Director(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True,null=True)
    photo=models.ImageField(upload_to='crew/director')
    slug=models.SlugField(max_length=50,unique=True,blank=True)
    about=models.TextField(max_length=2000,blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
class Writer(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True,null=True)
    photo=models.ImageField(upload_to='crew/writer')
    slug=models.SlugField(max_length=50,unique=True,blank=True)
    about=models.TextField(max_length=2000,blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
class Cinematographer(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True,null=True)
    photo=models.ImageField(upload_to='crew/cinematographer')
    slug=models.SlugField(max_length=50,unique=True,blank=True)
    about=models.TextField(max_length=2000,blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Genre(models.Model):
    genre=models.CharField(max_length=10,blank=True)
    movies=models.Foreignkey(Movie,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.genre
class Certification(models.Model):
    certification=models.CharField(max_length=10,blank=True)
    movies=models.Foreignkey(Movie,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.certification
class Streaming(models.Model):
    logo=models.ImageField(upload_to='streaming/logo',blank=True,null=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True,null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**movie\models.py**
I haven't put the actor field yet because i dont know how to add more than one values to a field.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from crew.models import *
from review_awards.models import *
# Create your models here.
class Movie(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True,blank=True)
    slug=models.SlugField(max_length=100,unique=True,blank=True)
    year=models.CharField(max_length=5,blank=True)
    language=models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    poster=models.ImageField(upload_to='movies/poster')
    cover=models.ImageField(upload_to='movies/cover',null=True)
    duration=models.CharField(max_length=50,default=None)
    streaming=models.ForeignKey(Streaming,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    ott=models.TextField(max_length=50,default='Prime Video')
    direct=models.ForeignKey(Director,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cinematography=models.ForeignKey(Cinematographer,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    writer=models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    based =models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
    genre=models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    awards=models.ForeignKey(Award,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    cri_reviews=models.ForeignKey(Critic_Review,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    aud_reviews=models.ForeignKey(Audience_Review,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    rating=models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True)
    certification=models.ForeignKey(Certification,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    synopsis=models.TextField(max_length=500,blank=True)
    trailer=models.TextField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I was expecting to add **actor, director** etc... on seperate tables and add all of these as foreign key to the **Movie** table.

Comment: Your two modules import each other.

Answer (score 0):

Your two modules import each other. That is the problem. In that case you can use a string literal with `'app_name.ModelName'` instead:

```
from django.db import models

# no from movie.models import Movie

# Create your models here.

# …

class Genre(models.Model):
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    movies = models.Foreignkey('movie.Movie', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.genre


class Certification(models.Model):
    certification = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    movies = models.Foreignkey('movie.Movie', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.certification

# …
```

The modeling is however quite strange for two reasons: `movies` hints that there are multiple ones, and you generate bidirectional relations. If you make a `ForeignKey` (or any other relation), Django will automatically generate a relation in reverse. So it makes no sense to add `movies` to the models:

```
from django.db import models

# no from movie.models import Movie

# Create your models here.

# …


class Genre(models.Model):
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    # no movies

    def __str__(self):
        return self.genre


class Certification(models.Model):
    certification = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    # no movies

    def __str__(self):
        return self.certification


# …
```

If you have a `Certification` and there are `Movie`s that refer to these, you can get a `QuerySet` of these movies with:

```
my_certification.movie_set.all()
```